# Ruby On Rails: How can I sort this hash by its keys in descending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
(rdb:60) p resultsHash
{ 1 => [#<Participant id: 6, username: "player2", online_rank: 7, created_at: "2011-05-14 04:49:22", updated_at: "2011-05-14 04:57:56", win_count: 1, device_type: "iPad">], 
  0 => [#<Participant id: 5, username: "player1", online_rank: 3, created_at: "2011-05-12 02:47:50", updated_at: "2011-05-12 02:47:50", win_count: 0, device_type: "iPad">, 
        #<Participant id: 4, username: "iPhone4Simulator", online_rank: 4, created_at: "2011-05-12 02:45:37", updated_at: "2011-05-12 02:45:37", win_count: 0, device_type: "iPad">]}
```

I've tried...

```
resultsHash.sort {|a,b| -(a[0]<=>b[0])}
```

but the results aren't sorted by the keys when I iterate through the hash using `each_pair`.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for Matthew Ratzloff's answer; also note that in Ruby 1.8.7 when you iterate a Hash, the keys are not guaranteed to be in any specific order. In Ruby 1.9.2, some order is maintained for the keys, so the hash will be in sorted order when iterated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you really want to do is add an ORDER BY clause to your query.  If this is Rails 3, `Participant.order(:id).all` is one way to do it.

To answer your immediate question, though, you would say `resultsHash.sort_by(&:id)`.  But don't do it this way.

Side note, use snake_case for Ruby code, not camelCase.

Edit: See comments.

Comment: thanks, matthew, but i actually want to sort by the keys of the top-most hash (in this case, the 1 and the 0), not the :id key of objects inside the hash.  your thoughts?

Comment: Ah.  I'm assuming you're setting the return value to a variable; otherwise you want `sort!`.  You can also just do `resultsHash.sort_by { |key, value| key.to_i }`.

Comment: nope, I wasn't, noob mistake, but when I change it to sort!, i get an undefined method 'sort!' error, what gives?  thanks again!

Comment: What gives is I told you wrong.  :-)  Active Support adds a `sort` method, but not `sort!`.  Assign it to a variable and you'll be fine.

Comment: i take it sort returns array?  i ask because when i assign the result of sort to a variable, the variable doesn't know what the each_pair method is.

Comment: Yep.  `foo.sort.each { |key, value| ... }`  You can also use the `Array#assoc` method (e.g., `foo.sort.assoc(2).last`) to access values by key like you would a hash.

Answer (score 2):

```
resultsHash.sort.reverse
```

Note that it'll return an Array of `[key, value]` pairs. But you can still iterate like with a Hash:

```
resultsHash.sort.reverse.each do |key, value|
  ....
end
```

Or you can retrieve only the values: `resultsHash.sort.reverse.map { |key, value| value }`, or `resultsHash.sort.reverse.map(&:last)`

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but one way you can do exactly what you want while still retaining a return type of `Hash` is to use `.slice` on the sorted keys:

```
resultHash.slice(*resultHash.keys.sort)
```